# count table with relationship vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, ado.net

I have 2 database table which is the office and the status. the status is consisting of defective, missing parts and lost. what i wanted to happen is whenever i choose an office the defective, missing parts and lost items from that office will be counted and displayed in a textbox or label.

Screenshots:

[image: APPLICATION]

[image: DATABASE]

```
sqlconnection.Open() 
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select Count(*) from cpfrtsdata where office = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' ", sqlconnection) 
Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar() 
cmd = Nothing 
sqlconnection.Close() 
Label3.Text = i
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear. Do you want help doing the counting logic or the display logic? You've told us what you want to happen, but not what you're having trouble with, or given us the code that's not behaving as expected.

Comment: sqlconnection.Open()

        
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select Count(*) from cpfrtsdata 

where office = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' ", sqlconnection)

        Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

        cmd = Nothing

        sqlconnection.Close()

        Label3.Text = i

i have this  code but this only display the total item in each office not every defective, missing parts or lost items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select Count(*) from cpfrtsdata where office = 'Carpentry Shop'` will return number of records having office equals `Carpentry Shop`. In order to get the total number of each `status`, you will need to issue the SQL transaction multiple times as follows:

```
Select Count(*) from cpfrtsdata where office = 'Carpentry Shop' and status = 'Defective'
Select Count(*) from cpfrtsdata where office = 'Carpentry Shop' and status = 'Lost'
```

and so on. Or you can modify your SQL to retrieve all in one transaction:

```
Select 
    sum(case status when 'Defective' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalDefective,
    sum(case status when 'Lost' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalLost,
    sum(case status when 'Missing Parts' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalMissingParts
from cpfrtsdata
where office = 'Carpentry Shop'
group by office
```

Since this query returns a table, you need to use [`MySqlDataAdapter`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/Methods_T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataAdapter.htm) or [`cmd.ExecuteReader`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_ExecuteReader.htm).

Comment: Very good! It took me a bit a playing in SSMS to figure it out. In SQL Server I didn't need the group by. Definitely an upvote.

Comment: You dont need the group by clause if you need to find the total for one specific office. But if you need to retrieve totals for each office in the result set, then you need the group by.

Comment: ("Select Count(*) from cpfrtsdata where office = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' and status = 'Defective' ", sqlconnection)

this is what i did so that whenever the user chose another office the system will only count the defective items in the selected office. thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would check is to verify you're getting a value back from the combobox. Step through the debugger and verify expected values. Then check to make sure you're getting a value from the query. Give your controls better names than ComboBox1 and Label3, it's too easy to use the wrong controls using the default names.

And I would switch from using the text property to the SelectedItem to get the value back from the control.

[MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=netframework-4.7.2) says about the combobox this:

> You can use these properties to manage the currently selected item in
>   the list, the Text property to specify the string displayed in the
>   editing field, the SelectedIndex property to get or set the current
>   item, and the SelectedItem property to get or set a reference to the
>   object.

```
Dim officeString As String = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

Also, you need to use parameters in your query to protect against SQL injection attacks